# Reading csv file converts it to json but it takes every row in it as a string in karate

Tags: json, csv, karate

I am able to read a csv file and convert it to json by

```
def expectedResponse = read('classpath:somefile.csv')
```

Suppose I have csv file as below

```
name,age
praveen,29
joseph,20
```

1.It is converting all elements as string and stores in the variable as json. How to keep the number as a number ? because it causes match failure which i do later with the actual response.

2.How to get the value 20. Like by specifying joseph, I want to get the age.
I got the jsonpath as

```
get expectedResponse $.[?(@.member == '<name>')].age
```

I get the name from examples. So I get it as joseph in runtime. But i get error as **reason: not equal (Integer : JSONArray)**. It is not returning the age alone (Integer value)

Or is there any better way to get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSV format does not contain any type information, so everything defaults to "string" and you *have* to convert it yourself. But this is easy using [`karate.map()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms).

```
* text users =
"""
name,age
praveen,29
joseph,20
"""
* csv users = users
* match users == [{ name: 'praveen', age: '29' }, { name: 'joseph', age: '20' }]
* def fun = function(x){ x.age = ~~x.age; return x }
* def users = karate.map(users, fun)
* match users == [{ name: 'praveen', age: 29 }, { name: 'joseph', age: 20 }]
```

Comment: May be it's worth mention that the [~~](http://rocha.la/JavaScript-bitwise-operators-in-practice) is a double bitwise operator and behaves like `Math.floor()`. 
So, it's a JavaScript and not a Karate feature.. ;-)